# Backup Solr home

Tags: backup, solr

I'm new to Solr: I've successfully installed Tomcat and Solr 4.3.1 webapp, and two collections on a CentOS 6.4 machine.

Now, my server is in production and I need to make backups of solr.

So, I would like to know what is the best way to backup solr...

For the moment I'm dooing: stop tomcat => tar of my solr home => start tomcat, but I've read that is not a good solution? Moreover, this implie to stop all the tomcat which have other webapps than solr.

I've also heard that there is a script named "backup" in solr home bin's folder ? but my bin folder is empty :(

I don't want to make an another slave server with replication, for me it's not a backup solution because my backup are supposed to be send to a bacula backup server all nights.

There is no builtin solution that I can work around to make a script ? like a mysqldump for Mysql servers.

Thanks for help !

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Backing+Up

Comment: Why would you need to backup Solr? Aren't you just indexing data that originates elsewhere? That data should be backed up but you should have a process to re-index the source data.